# find / remove superfluous edges from a polygon

Tags: python, algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry

I am looking for an algorithm to obtain the outer hull of a set of linked vertices: the black line in the figure. The figure is a combination of sets of linked vertices, resulting in superfluous vertices and edges. The image shows the idea: the edges in red need to be removed.

The data looks like: (v00, v01, v02, ...), (v10, v11, v12, ...), ... The data does share common nodes (the numerical data of the vertex is identical).

[image]

Can this be done?

Thank you

PS. The target code is Python. Anything close to Python would be perfect.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Can you add example input along with desired output?

Comment: Are you looking for a convex hull?

Comment: The polygon in your picture is not convex; however if all polygons under consideration are convex, an algorithm for computing the convex hull polygon of all vertices might help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms The possibilites also depend a bit on the representation of polygons in your specific setting.

Comment: Please, edit the question to include the input and desired output exactly as you want it. The illustration is helpful, but it is harder to reason about natural language descriptions of datastructures than actual data structures.

Comment: Are the vertices different, but (nearly) coincident or are they the same? That is, do the polygons share common nodes?

Comment: The put-on-hold may because of unclear question be true for some, but n.m. understood it perfectly. I am sorry that others did not get it. I tried to be as clear as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a list of vertices with their coordinates, and a list of edges.
2. For each vertex, sort its incident edges *by the angle* counterclockwise.
3. Start with the leftmost vertex (leftmost-lowermost if there are several).
4. Pick the first edge with the angle >-π/2.
5. Traverse the edge.
6. Pick the first edge that comes after the incoming edge in the sorted order.
7. If this is not the vertex you have started with, go to 5.

This will build the list of outer edges.

If you have more than one polygon, you may remove the connected component of the graph you have started with, and repeat the algorithm all over. Note that it does not recognize polygons with holes. If you have holes, you will need to run separate tests to find out which contour is inside which.

Comment: This is it!. One catch: when there is a vertex on an edge in one shape but not on the other, rounding errors might/will give problems. So it is needed to look one step (edge/vertex) further to detect these problems.

Comment: Rounding errors are a huge problem in computational geometry. Reduce the problem to one with integer coordinates if you can.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you want to compute the infinite face of a [planar straight-line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) represented as a list of line segments, e.g., like

```
[((x1, y1), (x2, y2)), ((x3, y3), (x4, y4)), ...].
```

The first step is to compute the combinatorial embedding. Insert each segment and its reverse into a dict of lists like so. (All of this Python is **untested**.)

```
graph = collections.defaultdict(list)
for p1, p2 in segments:
    graph[p1].append(p2)
    graph[p2].append(p1)
```

Now, sort each list by angle. I'm going to use `atan2` for simplicity.

```
for (x1, y1), p2s in graph.items():
    p2s.sort(key=lambda (x2, y2): math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
```

Find a vertex on the infinite face. The <strike>bottommost, breaking ties by leftmost</strike> leftmost will do (the code breaks ties by bottommost, not that it matters).

```
v0 = min(graph.keys())
```

The first edge on `v0`'s adjacency list is oriented counterclockwise on the infinite face. Start with its reverse, which is oriented clockwise.

```
e0 = (graph[v0][0], v0)
```

Now, iterate edges in the following fashion.

```
e = e0
while True:
    yield e
    v = e[1]
    neighbors = graph[v]
    e = (v, neighbors[neighbors.index(e[0]) - 1])
    if e == e0:
        break
```

Given a directed edge oriented clockwise on the infinite face, the next edge is obtained by reversing it, then locating the next edge with the same tail in clockwise order. Repeat until we return to the starting edge.

Comment: I need to think this over, but it looks like this what I am looking for. Thank you! I will return on this.